# AngularJS ul, li selection

Tags: html, angularjs, html-lists

how to select croissant (the one with class 'selected' ) to $scope.selected variable in angular ?

```
<ul id='ulsel' placement="top-left" style="max-height: 154px;">
<li value="Apple fritter" class="" tabindex="-1">Apple fritter</li>
<li value="Croissant" tabindex="-1" class="selected">Croissant</li>
<li value="Donut" tabindex="-1" class="">Donut</li>
<li value="Financier" tabindex="-1" class="">Financier</li>
<li value="Jello" tabindex="-1">Jello</li><li value="Madeleine" tabindex="-1">Madeleine</li>
<li value="Pound cake" tabindex="-1">Pound cake</li>
<li value="Pretzel" tabindex="-1">Pretzel</li>
<li value="Sfogliatelle" tabindex="-1">Sfogliatelle</li></ul>
```

Comment: can you post the js code you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is very strange, `li`'s having values attributes and using a class as selected rather then a input is an unusually approach. Regardless you can use the below:

```
$scope.selected = $('#ulsel li.selected').html();
```

This just gets the text inside the `li` with the `selected` class.
I have used the text inside the element rather then the value attribute you have put on, as I'm not sure how supported that's going to be

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with atmd.  I'd instead have Angular build the li's with ng-repeat, then you have much more control instead of relying on jQuery to parse.

Here's another way to get the value with jQuery:

```
$scope.selected = $("#ulsel").find('.selected').attr('value');
```

Works in Chrome, didn't test further.